# How to join 6th Table with field without repeating?

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports, oracle10g

First of all apology for " " all over, it is part of Crystal Report.

I have this query, it is written by someone else, I need to add another table but I don't want values to repeat if added tables has more rows of data.

Original query

```
select 
        "t1"."ID",
        "t4"."CURR",
        "t3"."TIME",
        "t4"."CASE",
        "t5"."CASE_TYPE"

from            
                "db"."t1" "t1"
full outer join "db"."t2" "t2" on "t1"."id"="t2"."id"
full outer join "db"."t3" "t3" on "t1"."id"="t3"."id"
full outer join "db"."t4" "t4" on "t1"."curr_name"="t4"."curr_id"
full outer join "db"."t5" "t5" on "t2"."cat"="t5"."cat"
```

Here is how it looks now
[image: exp1]

I need to JOIN another table `t6` it's `id` = to `t1`.`id`, and add field new1, new2

but I want Current,Time,Case,Cause_Type to be null if t6.new1 and new2 has more data.
example
[image: img2]

How can I join t6 without having red and strikethrough values repeat?

Comment: YOu can't SQL doesn't work that way. You do presentation in the application.

Comment: Because you have different data in one of the fields, so that is a new row.

Comment: is there a way to write to select statement and use union all or something, I am noob to SQL.

Comment: You will have to use `left or right outer joins` to be able to do what you want. Also, I would recommend re-structuring the query and write it in a more elegant way.

Comment: NO there is NOT a way to do this. This is SQL 101 stuff, you have to return the whole record. If you don't want every field to deisplay you do that in the application. YOu do ever do presentation inteh sql code.

Comment: [this-link](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/ms-sql/threads/186025/removing-duplicates-from-inner-join-of-two-tables) how did they do it here?

Comment: If this is in Crystal Reports, why create a query at all? Just let CR handle the joins and do the presentation inside of the report.

Comment: @Ryan if you talking about, like draging field into the report and let it do the work? then I tired that I work for 1st 5 table, if I add this 6th table it won't join it, I dont know what CR handle is, I will need to real about it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mogli try this:
I'm guessing that the t6 field is a table that holds multiple records based off of 1 id# based on what you're showing above.

in CR database, add the table and then add in the new table, under links join t6.id to t1.id with a left outer join (going from t1 to t6)
on the report itself create a group using the t1.id, then add a second group with the fields you want to use from t6.

if you are looking for a specific record on t6 see if the table has a row that has the "current" Id in it and add a join for that between the tables (you may be able to remove the join initial join between t1.id & t6.id)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "ID"
,"CURR"
,"TIME"
,"CASE"
,"CASE_TYPE"
,New1
,New2
FROM (
    SELECT "t1"."ID"
    ,"t4"."CURR"
    ,"t3"."TIME"
    ,"t4"."CASE"
    ,"t5"."CASE_TYPE"
    ,SUM("New1") OVER (
        PARTTION BY "t1"."ID" ORDER BY "t1"."ID"
        ) AS New1
    ,SUM("New2") OVER (
        PARTTION BY "t1"."ID" ORDER BY "t1"."ID"
        ) AS New2
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTTION BY "t1"."ID" ORDER BY "t1"."ID"
        ) AS RowNum
    FROM "db"."t1" "t1"
    FULL OUTER JOIN "db"."t2" "t2"
        ON "t1"."id" = "t2"."id"
    FULL OUTER JOIN "db"."t3" "t3"
        ON "t1"."id" = "t3"."id"
    FULL OUTER JOIN "db"."t4" "t4"
        ON "t1"."curr_name" = "t4"."curr_id"
    FULL OUTER JOIN "db"."t5" "t5"
        ON "t2"."cat" = "t5"."cat"
    FULL OUTER JOIN "db"."t6" "t6"
        ON "t6"."id" = "t1"."id"
    ) Tb1
WHERE RowNum = 1
```